# A whole new level

Tags: phrases

I often hear the following phrases in movies and some of my colleagues have started using it.

- This takes it up to the next level
- This is a whole new level

I'm just wondering whether this is game speak or did it exist before platform games.  I am interested in when the phrase is used as a sentence by itself.

Comment: Either it goes back to Klingon 3-dimensional chess first introduced here in 1842, or perhaps to a [Moral Re-Armament](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22whole+new+level%22&lr=lang_en&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1800,cd_max:1968,lr:lang_1en,sbd:1&tbm=bks&source=lnt&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwim_IDV8OvfAhVLMqwKHSIjDCQQpwUIIQ&biw=1124&bih=512&dpr=1.5) in 1940.

Comment: I'm sure that I remember it from the 1960s; well before small computers, let alone electronic games with levels.

Comment: The 1940s reference is actually __a whole new level of thinking__  .  I've clarified the question.  I am interested in when there is a full stop at the end of level.

Comment: So?  It's always going to be a new level of SOMETHING, even if that thing is implied and not explicitly stated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If, say, a worker takes a complaint to the next level of management or a high school student takes a science project to the next level of competition, when either *takes it to the next level*, the pronoun has a definite antecedent and the level is a concrete, logical progression. In the expression you’re asking about, neither may be the case:

> 1. Analyze the media system to increase its effectiveness and/or efficiency.
>      1.1 Do you evaluate the school community’s knowledge of the media center’s resources by means of a questionnaire?
>      1.2 Do you review the results of this questionnaire with your peers and [*take it to the next level*](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=mdp.39015009340566;view=1up;seq=17;skin=mobile) where necessary? — *Performance criteria for evaluating the library/media program in Michigan schools*, Michigan Department of Education, State Library Services, ca. 1975.

There is no logical next step in a discussion about questionnaire results, and the pronoun does not unambiguously refer to their review. The author seems instead to be encouraging a deeper, perhaps more detailed conversation.

The phrase seems to have been a favorite of a New York congressman:

> Mr. Rosenthal (Benjamin, D-NY). When the Internal Revenue Service makes a recommendation to Treasury, it is an important public event.
>   Mr. Kurt (Jerome, IRS Commissioner)  Whether it is public or not
>   Mr. Rosenthal. It is an important event.
>   Really I should explore this with my colleagues and not with you. Shouldn’t it be a matter of public interest? Then we can [*take it to the next level*](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=mdp.39015081169768;view=1up;seq=391;skin=mobile) and deal with Treasury. — Hearing: “Foreign Tax Credits Claimed by US Petroleum Companies,” House Cmte. on Gov. Operations; Commerce, Consumer, and Monetary Affairs Subcmte., 29 Nov. 1977.
>
> Mr. Rosenthal. If they do not reach an agreement, then we will [*take it to the next level*](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=mdp.39015082027890;view=plaintext;seq=228;skin=mobile). Then we intend to subpena (sic) all the records.  — Hearing: “Interest Rate Regulation on Small Savings,” House Cmte. on Gov. Operations; Commerce, Consumer, and Monetary Affairs Subcmte., 6 April 1979.

If you agree that these examples are the same as what one hears today, then their early date precludes any influence from video games.

Beginning in the late 1980s, the expression would become all but ubiquitous in the 1990s. In many cases, the expression simply means doing something better, bigger, faster, deeper, etc. than before:

> “He [Tom Hanks] didn't go for the cliche,” says Big co-star Elizabeth Perkins. “It could easily have been, ‘Look, gee whiz, I'm a big guy playing this little kid.’ But Tom brought a sense of fear to this person. He showed that this child was afraid, extremely scared, extremely vulnerable. Tom [*took it to the next level*](https://cdnc.ucr.edu/cgi-bin/cdnc?a=d&d=SBS19880605.1.100&e=-------en--20--1--txt-txIN-%252522it+to+the+next+level%252522-------1).” — *San Bernadino Sun*, 5 June 1988.
>
> We knew that after winning the nationals, everyone was coming at us. So we knew we had to [*push it to the next level*](https://cdnc.ucr.edu/cgi-bin/cdnc?a=d&d=SCS19900511.1.51&e=-------en--20--1--txt-txIN-%252522it+to+the+next+level%252522-------1) to stay ahead.  — *Santa Cruz Sentinel*, 11May 1990.
>
> “It has been seven years and I’m happy with the progress Aenon [Bible College] has made. The school needs a fulltime president now to [*take it to the next level*](https://newspapers.library.in.gov/cgi-bin/indiana?a=d&d=INR19910629-01.1.10&txq=%22it+to+the+next+level%22).” — *Indianapolis Recorder*, 29 June 1991.
>
> In March 1977 Olsen was named president and CEO. “I inherited the management of a successful company,” recalls Olsen. “My whole project was to [*take it to the next level*](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=mdp.39015029302745;view=1up;seq=507;skin=mobile).” — *CDA Journal*(CA Dental Assn.), June 1992.
>
> “Hopefully, I can [*take it to the next level*](https://stanforddailyarchive.com/cgi-bin/stanford?a=d&d=stanford19921106-01.2.29&txq=%22it+to+the+next+level%22), because I've got to take care of my mom. That's what it all boils down to. I'll worry about myself after.” If he doesn't find a niche in the NFL, Lasley will probably use his economics major to foray into the business world. — *The Stanford Daily*, 6 Nov. 1992.
>
> “(Bailey) is definitely ready to [*take it to the next level*](https://archive.org/details/ucladailybruin155losa/page/n146?q=%22it+to+the+next+level%22),” said UCLA sophomore Charles O'Bannon. “He still needs to work on his perimeter game and his fundamentals.” — *Daily Bruin*, 15 Aug. 1994.

At some point in the new century, the expression became a euphemism for beginning a sexual relationship after a period of dating:

> “Charmed,” November 23, 2003, 8 p.m. EST; three female characters are talking; … Later, one of the female characters talks about being afraid to “[*take it to the next level*](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=uc1.31210019948148;view=1up;seq=703;skin=mobile)” with her boyfriend, and another character tells her to “relax and let it happen.” She replies: “That's easy for you to say, you weren't the one sleeping with an angel for three years.” — *FCC Record*, 20, No. 3, January 18 - January 31, 2005.